# Reporting Services inconsistent results between text output and preview

Tags: reporting-services

We are running MS Reporting Services 2012. We have a simple query that only passes in a date to run. When the query is run in the Data tab, the correct results are displayed, however when the same query is run in the Preview tab all the columns, except the Amount column display the exact same (repeated data of the first line) - the amount column displays the changing amounts correctly.

This is really weird considering that it is the exact same query for both views.

We have looked into any settings in the report itself to see if there is anything there in Properties and Parameters that may be causing this behavior but it is all bog standard with no filters/values set.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

JR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new report from scratch and this seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you dont set your report langauge. If in your report properties under **Localization > Language** the value is blank, SSRS doesnt know which regional format to display for date values. And the textbox default settings for dates is the format for the regional settings (They start with `*`).

I had this issue by myself. The date field looked totally ridiciulas, after I added the report language everything was fine.